# Capturing emoticons using regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

I would like to have a regex pattern to match smileys ":)" ,":(" .Also it should capture repeated smileys like ":) :)" , ":) :(" but filter out invalid syntax like ":( (" .

I have this with me, but it matches ":( ("

```
bool( re.match("(:\()",str) )
```

I maybe missing something obvious here, and I'd like some help for this seemingly simple task.

Comment: Is `:( (` invalid, or a combination of valid and invalid?

Comment: it is invalid. only smileys and repeated smileys are valid.

Comment: Then you should specify the entire string using `^` and `$`.. as it stands it successfully matches any similey *somewhere* in the string

Comment: thank you..i missed that point. let me try again with it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it finally "clicked" exactly what you're asking about here. Take a look at the below:

```
import re

smiley_pattern = '^(:\(|:\))+$' # matches only the smileys ":)" and ":("

def test_match(s):
    print 'Value: %s; Result: %s' % (
        s,
        'Matches!' if re.match(smiley_pattern, s) else 'Doesn\'t match.'
    )

should_match = [
    ':)',   # Single smile
    ':(',   # Single frown
    ':):)', # Two smiles
    ':(:(', # Two frowns
    ':):(', # Mix of a smile and a frown
]
should_not_match = [
    '',         # Empty string
    ':(foo',    # Extraneous characters appended
    'foo:(',    # Extraneous characters prepended
    ':( :(',    # Space between frowns
    ':( (',     # Extraneous characters and space appended
    ':(('       # Extraneous duplicate of final character appended
]

print('The following should all match:')
for x in should_match: test_match(x);

print('')   # Newline for output clarity

print('The following should all not match:')
for x in should_not_match: test_match(x);
```

The problem with your original code is that your regex is wrong: `(:\()`. Let's break it down.

The outside parentheses are a "grouping". They're what you'd reference if you were going to do a string replacement, and are used to apply regex operators on groups of characters at once. So, you're really saying:

- `(` begin a group

  - `:\(` ... do regex stuff ...
- ')' end the group

The `:` isn't a regex reserved character, so it's just a colon. The `\` is, and it means "the following character is literal, not a regex operator". This is called an "escape sequence". Fully parsed into English, your regex says

- `(` begin a group

  - `:` a colon character
  - `\(` a left parenthesis character
- `)` end the group

The regex I used is slightly more complex, but not bad. Let's break it down: `^(:\(|:\))+$`.

`^` and `$` mean "the beginning of the line" and "the end of the line" respectively. Now we have ...

- `^` beginning of line

  - `(:\(|:\))+` ... do regex stuff ...
- `$` end of line

... so it only matches things that comprise the entire line, not simply occur in the middle of the string.

We know that `(` and `)` denote a grouping. `+` means "one of more of these". Now we have:

- `^` beginning of line
- `(` start a group

  - `:\(|:\)` ... do regex stuff ...
- `)` end the group
- `+` match one or more of this
- `$` end of line

Finally, there's the `|` (pipe) operator. It means "or". So, applying what we know from above about escaping characters, we're ready to complete the translation:

- `^` beginning of line
- `(` start a group

  - `:` a colon character
  - `\(` a left parenthesis character
- `|` or

  - `:` a colon character
  - `\)` a right parenthesis character
- `)` end the group
- `+` match one or more of this
- `$` end of line

I hope this helps. If not, let me know and I'll be happy to edit my answer with a reply.

Comment: Thank you. Even though I had managed to solve it on my own, your incredibly well explained answer helped to clear a lot of regex concepts for me.

Comment: Good to hear you got it taken care of, and I'm glad my explanation helped :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like:

```
re.match('[:;][)(](?![)(])', str)
```

Comment: urm..could you explain what exactly does it do?

Comment: This regex will match either a `;` or a `:`, followed by either a `)` or `(`, but only when it is then NOT followed by another `)` or `(`.  This is probably not the perfect solution, but is at least another way to look at the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try `(?::|;|=)(?:-)?(?:\)|\(|D|P)`. Haven't tested it extensively, but does seem to match the right ones and not more...

```
In [15]: import re

In [16]: s = "Just: to :)) =) test :(:-(( ():: :):) :(:( :P ;)!"

In [17]: re.findall(r'(?::|;|=)(?:-)?(?:\)|\(|D|P)',s)
Out[17]: [':)', '=)', ':(', ':-(', ':)', ':)', ':(', ':(', ':P', ';)']
```

Comment: thank you..whats the meaning of (? ..)? I read the documentation, but couldn't understand. I'd be happy if you could explain the pattern a lil bit..

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer I was looking for from the comments and answers posted here.

```
re.match("^(:[)(])*$",str)
```

Thanks to all.

Comment: This regex will only work if `str` starts with `:` and only contains repetitions of `:)` and `:(` all the way to the end.  Are you sure this is what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. I'm sorry for not being able to post the question correctly enough. And thanks for answering.

Comment: Hmm... Are you *sure* you're sure? :)  The following string would match this regex: `:):):):):(:(:):(:)`. That doesn't seem useful from this side of the monitor.

Comment: Also, an empty string matches. `*` Means "zero or more occurrences". `+` Means "one or more occurrences," and `?` means "Zero or one occurrences."

Comment: Yes, I agree it doesn't make sense generally. But I was using it to solve a programming contest problem.